# How do I create a series of methods in expression engine for actions and output of a bespoke page in the admin area?

Tags: php, administration

We are trying to create a new page in the Expression Engine administration area, ideally using a custom module or extension.

We need a method that EE with call before the header is sent to the browser and a method to display any output. This is generic and will have no specific function but the documentation on this is scarce.

For example in WordPress, I would add some custom actions to the init hook and call the 'add_menu_page' method in the functions.php file. One of the input variables of this method is a bespoke PHP file containing the output.

In short I need to know how to do the equivalent in EE2 as it is not as clearly documented as WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the simplest solution was to use http://pkg.io/ to generate the basic extension classes for you, allowing any competent programmer to fill in the gaps to produce the user interface.